# Accessing joined table data

Tags: acumatica

Here is the modified code and the error I am getting.  Using debug I have confirmed it is happening on the:

```
var ret = cmd.Select();
```

[image]

Here is the full code.

```
[PXFilterable]
public PXFilteredProcessing<EDASNShipProj, EDCreateASNFilter> Shipment;

protected virtual IEnumerable shipment()
{
    int ii = 0;
    foreach (var row in Shipment.Cache.Cached)
    {
        ii++;
        yield return row;
    }
    if (ii == 0)
    {            
    var cmd = new PXSelectJoin<SOShipment,
        LeftJoin<SOOrderShipment, On<SOShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr>>,
        LeftJoin<SOOrder, On<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr>>>>,
        Where2<Where2<Where2<Where2<Where2<Where2<Where2<
                Where<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.customerID>, IsNull,
                    Or<SOOrderExt.usrEDICustomerId, Equal<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.customerID>>>>,
            And<Where<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.startDate>, IsNull,
                    Or<SOShipment.shipDate, GreaterEqual<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.startDate>>>>>>,
            And<Where<SOShipment.shipDate, LessEqual<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.endDate>>>>>,
            And<Where<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.shipVia>, IsNull,
                    Or<SOShipment.shipVia, Equal<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.shipVia>>>>>>,
            And<Where<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.truckNbr>, IsNull,
                    Or<SOShipmentExt.usrTruckNbr, Equal<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.truckNbr>>>>>>,
            And<Where<SOShipment.status, Equal<SOShipmentStatus.open>>>>,
            And<Where<SOShipmentExt.usrEDIStatus, Equal<SOShipmentEDIStatus.truckAssigned>,
                    Or<SOShipmentExt.usrEDIStatus, Equal<SOShipmentEDIStatus.newStat>>>>>,
            And<Where<SOOrder.customerRefNbr, IsNotNull>>>,
        OrderBy<Asc<SOShipment.customerID,
                Asc<SOOrderExt.usrEDICustomerId,
                Asc<SOOrderExt.usrEDICustomerVendorId,
                Asc<SOShipment.shipVia,
                Asc<SOShipmentExt.usrTruckNbr,
                Asc<SOShipment.customerLocationID>>>>>>>>(this);
    cmd.View.Clear();
    var ret = cmd.Select();
    if (ret != null)
    {
        EDASNShipProj shipProj = new EDASNShipProj();
        foreach (PXResult<SOShipment, SOOrderShipment, SOOrder> record in ret)
        {
            shipProj = new EDASNShipProj();
            SOShipment shipment = (SOShipment)record;
            SOShipmentExt soShipmentExt = shipment.GetExtension<SOShipmentExt>();
            SOOrder soOrder = (SOOrder)record;
            SOOrderExt soOrderExt = soOrder.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>();
            shipProj.OrderNbr = soOrder.OrderNbr;
            shipProj.CustomerRefNbr = soOrder.CustomerRefNbr;
            shipProj.CustomerOrderNbr = soOrder.CustomerOrderNbr;
            shipProj.UsrTruckNbr = soShipmentExt.UsrTruckNbr;
            shipProj.UsrEDICustomerId = soOrderExt.UsrEDICustomerId;
            shipProj.UsrEDICustomerVendorId = soOrderExt.UsrEDICustomerVendorId;
            shipProj.UsrEDIStatus = soShipmentExt.UsrEDIStatus;
            shipProj.CustomerID = shipment.CustomerID;
            shipProj.CustomerLocationID = shipment.CustomerLocationID;
            shipProj.ShipVia = shipment.ShipVia;
            shipProj.ShipmentNbr = shipment.ShipmentNbr;
            shipProj.ShipDate = shipment.ShipDate;
            shipProj = Shipment.Insert(shipProj);
            Shipment.Cache.SetStatus(shipProj, PXEntryStatus.Held);
            yield return shipProj;
        }
    }
    Shipment.Cache.IsDirty = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that Select() returns a PXResultset of the main DAC. You can then loop over this and cast to the joined DACs.

Here is an example :

```cs
// The static Select() method is called to execute a BQL command.
PXResultset<OrderDetail> result =
    PXSelectJoin<OrderDetail, InnerJoin<SalesOrder,
        On<SalesOrder.orderNbr, Equal<OrderDetail.orderNbr>>>>.Select(this);

// Iterating over the result set:
// PXResult should be specialized with the DACs of all joined tables
// to be able to cast to these DACs.
foreach(PXResult<OrderDetail, SalesOrder> record in result)
{
    // Casting a result set record to the OrderDetail DAC:
    OrderDetail detail = (OrderDetail)record;
    // Casting a result set record to the SalesOrder DAC:
    SalesOrder order = (SalesOrder)record;
    ...
}
```

Please have a look at this article for more information

https://help.acumatica.com/(W(8))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=8609c829-7b9c-4660-acf9-891b0971b6a3

Comment: OK! I think  I figured it out with your help.  I thought the foreach loop variable would be the primary DAC from the select but it appears to work better to explicitly type all the DACs.  Thanks.

Comment: I updated my code to be similar to this example, but now I am getting a strange error regarding a field I am not even using. The error is occurring on the actual cmd.Select().  See the modified code above in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the type that is inferred when you use var:
[image]

'a' is of type 'PXResultset < ARSalesPerTran > ' in this example

If I were to assign it to another variable 'b' of a different type like 'PXResultset < ARSalesPerTran, ARSalesPerTranExt, ARRegister > ' the compiler will report that it can't implicitly cast 'PXResultset < ARSalesPerTran > ' to 'PXResult < ARSalesPerTran, ARSalesPerTranExt, ARRegister > '.

```
PXResult<ARSalesPerTran, ARSalesPerTranExt, ARRegister> b = a;
```

[image]

However the compiler will allow an explicit cast:

```
PXResult<ARSalesPerTran, ARSalesPerTranExt, ARRegister> b = (PXResult< ARSalesPerTran, ARSalesPerTranExt, ARRegister>)a;
```

In a nutshell, this is related to an artifact of C# inferred type system (var) rather than an Acumatica feature.